# How to orchestrate logstash instances

Tags: logstash, scheduling, job-scheduling, instances, orchestration

Please guys, I have a situation in which I have to run multiple instances scheduled in different time, I need a good tool for scheduling all these instances in an advanced way, I need to check if logstash has completed its job to start another script... 
I really can't use this kind of solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656184/kill-logstash-when-finished-parsing) like killing logstash instance because I'm not reading from file, it's much more complicated

So there are two main questions :

*) How to check if logstash has completed its job ?

*) what is the best tool to orchestrate these instances ?

I start using [Job Scheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/jobscheduler) but I really don't know if it's the good choice, any help ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: For some inputs, Logstash will never exit, for others it will. So can you explain in a bit more details your overall architecture and where Logstash should kick in, what it reads from and where it writes to?

Comment: there is log4j input for example, some rest calls from exec input and all goes to Elasticsearch, I have some ETL works which must be included in the orchestration work... @Val